# What components can be used as an alternative to vibration motors?

Tags: components, component-selection, vibration, vibration-motor

I am building a project that will vibrate at certain times. The item being vibrated is 300-700 grams (still working out the material). It needs to be a noticable vibration (like a phone vibration), not a "paint-can-shake."

Are there alternatives to components such as vibration motors or  a taptic engine?

I need to do 1000-5000 seconds of vibration over 1-2 weeks, on a single battery charge.

If I go with a vibration motor, is there a way I can estimate the needed specs, or do I have to try ten of them?

Comment: What frequency and amplitude and what type of mass are you vibrating? In other words, are you testing something's ability to withstand vibration, or are you creating tactile feedback for a user? There's a big difference between vibrating a 10kg product in a test fixture and vibrating as a means of user feedback.

Comment: And also, how is it mounted? Vibrating a rigid 10kg mass, attached to a large reaction mass via springs, at the resonant frequency, is a far sight easier than doing it over a range of frequencies, or vibrating a less rigid, lossy or free mass. Amplitude is key, because at some point, enough energy will be required that the object becomes 100% battery (or a bit further if a fuel engine is allowed -- higher energy density).

Comment: @JYelton OP enhanced, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a XY question. You've told us what you don't want rather than telling us what you're requirements are.

In order to vibrate something it will take a certain amount of energy. The amount of energy will depend on the mass of what you're trying to move, how much it has to move, how long it has to move for, and the efficiency of the motor used to move it. It may be that the things you've ruled out are actually the best thing to use in your situation but without specifics it's impossible to tell.

There are several ways to get motion electronically, there's electromagnetism, electrostatic force, the piezoelectric effect, and using heat such as with [Nitinol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_titanium) wire. Other technologies are [electroactive polymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroactive_polymer) and [electrorheological fluids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrorheological_fluid). Which ones will be most useful for you depends on your specific use case.

Comment: OP enhanced....